# How do I factory reset/wipe Galaxy Note 2 with no screen?

Tags: factory-reset, broken-screen

My phone's LCD is broken but the rest of the phone works 100%. I can't do the normal steps to erase the phone because I can't interact with the menu on the screen to do so. I would like to erase everything so I can sell the phone to somebody willing to have the screen repaired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Hold volume up + Home + Power Key wait for 3 mins
2. Press volume down 3 times
3. Press power button
4. Press volume down 6 times
5. Press power key

That will do a hard reset.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm going through the same thing with the same phone. How do you confirm that your phone has been reset since you can't see the screen?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Android SDK installed on your computer (otherwise, see e.g. [Is there a minimal installation of ADB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575)), you can use the `fastboot` utility for that – provided *USB Debugging* was activated on the device (which might be the default in recovery mode):

```
fastboot erase data
fastboot erase cache
```

These two commands should erase everything from the `/data` (user-apps and data) plus `/cache` (app cache) partitions. So then you only had to take care for information stored on the SDCard(s), which you could erase e.g. via UMS/MTP (concerning the internal SD). There might be ways to do this via `fastboot` as well.

Take care to not erase things like system or recovery, as that would render the Android system unusable – which is not what you want. Entering the `fastboot` command without parameters lists up what you can do with this utility (syntax etc.).

For more details, you might want to watch some introductionary video: [Fastboot clean erase tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DgbGX6W7EqM): that describes a complete erase of the device, followed by a re-flash.

Answer (score 1):

1. Hold Volume Up + Home + Power key
2. Wait for three **seconds**
3. Release buttons
4. Press Volume Down three times
5. Press Power button
6. Press Volume Down **seven** times
7. Press Power key

That will do a hard reset.

1. Wait 60 seconds.
2. Hit Power again and it will reboot the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these answers worked for me when this happened to my friends phone. USB debugging was never turned on because she had no need for it. The screen however was completely busted after being dropped face down on the sidewalk. The only way that I could find to clear her data was to connect the Galaxy Note 2 to my Ubuntu box and delete all the directories except for "Android" and the "device_id.txt" file. I hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score -1):

If your device is registered with [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) you can erase from that site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but we expect details. Please mention how should that Manager be used to erase the app.