# Bad LCD, Reset to Factory

Tags: factory-reset

I have a galaxy sII (i9200m) updated to the latest firmware and would like to do a factory reset. I have no idea how as the LCD is completely shot (solid black).

Hope you can help.

Thank you

Comment: You might wish to take a look at [How do I factory reset/wipe Galaxy Note 2 with no screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54521/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have no access to the UI, the option would be using the [adb](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) shell.

Note: the adb shell will Only work if USB debugging was Previously enabled!

Connect your device with the USB cable. (install drivers if needed)
Use a terminal (or cmd if in windows) Change to your adb location directory. Run the following to do a recovery wipe:

```
adb shell
> recovery --wipe_data
```